# How (if possible) can I change the color option for the highlighted search results in eclipse (Moonrise theme)?

Tags: eclipse, themes

I've changed my Eclipse Kepler (SR2) theme to Moonrise 0.8.9

Now the color of the highlighted objects makes the results barely visible.
I haven't found any option to modify either the color of the text, or the color of the background

I've attached the Search view

[image: Eclipse, search result]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To change the highlighted row search result go to:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic
```

and change the `Match highlight background color`.

Note: This will not change the color of the other search results that are in purple

Comment: Works beautifully for text searches, but I'm still stuck with grey-on-purple for C++ reference searches. Do you know where I can find that color preference?

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ > Build > Makefile Editor > Matching brackets highlight

[image: picture]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.