# How to change highlight color of references in Search View in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, color-scheme

I want to change the highlight color of references showing in Eclipse's Search View after CDT find reference operation (right click on code -> References -> any). How can I do this?

Note: this is different from standard [match highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425937/how-if-possible-can-i-change-the-color-option-for-the-highlighted-search-resul).

Illustration:
[image]

Comment: solution found in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922934/how-to-change-search-background-color-in-eclipse/10955355 by @MasterHD's reply

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out two easy solutions to this problem:

**1) Create a new file and add those lines (extension of the file needs to be .epf):**

```
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.ColoredLabels.match_highlight=128,0,128
```

You might change the color value to match your theme

Then go to File -> Import -> General -> Preferences

Browse to the newly created file and click the Finish button

**2) Go to [workspace-location]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings**

Edit org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs file and add the line

```
org.eclipse.cdt.ui.ColoredLabels.match_highlight=128,0,128
```

Comment: Both does the same thing anyway. The 1st one is better if you intend to share your theme as it's the native way to proceed

Comment: Really useful, I have added this info to [Bug 468206](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468206)

Comment: Also you can set `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.ColoredLabels.writeaccess_highlight` in the same way for the beige write access highlights.

Comment: Check out this for perfect answer: :)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24426115/2524584)

Comment: Gents, there are news of some possible easier (purely-GUI-based solution) for Neon (disclaimer: I haven't tried it):
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468206
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922934/how-to-change-search-background-color-in-eclipse/10955355

Comment: none of these workaround work for me, neither Neon nor Oxygen

Answer (score 3):

It seems that these colours are not editable and are therefore hard coded in a way that (clearly!) does not work well with a dark theme.

This is the relevant part from the [org.eclipse.cdt.ui/plugin.xml](https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/blob/master/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/plugin.xml#L624):

```xml
  <colorDefinition
        id="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.ColoredLabels.match_highlight"
        isEditable="false"
        label="%Dummy.label"
        value="206, 204, 247">
  </colorDefinition>
```

A small change to the plugin.xml allows the colour to be editable:

```xml
  <colorDefinition
        categoryId="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.presentation"
        id="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.ColoredLabels.match_highlight"
        isEditable="true"
        label="Match Highlight"
        value="206, 204, 247">
  </colorDefinition>
```

And then you can edit the background colour and fix your problem.

This is a known issue in CDT ([Bug 468206](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468206)), contributions welcome.

Comment: I tried to edit the `plugin.xml` from the jar and repack it, not working neither :(

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that works for me. With eclipse closed:

- unpack `<eclipse installation folder>\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.ui_6.3.0.201802261533.jar`
- edit `plugin.xml` and change the color to your taste
- put this file back into the jar
- delete `<eclipse installation folder>\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.mainData.1`
- start eclipse